# Magento 2 How to dynamically change custom attributes when click on the color attributes in the configurable product?

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.3, ajax, color-swatches

I need dynamically change custom attribute on the configurable page when I click to the swatch color attribute. On this purpose I programmatically created custom attributes with options on the admin panel, where I can save for every product his own custom attributes.

I figure out how to call my custom attributes  on simple products but I can't to do this with configurable product.

I see when I change color attribute - price is changed for every simple product(it's default thing), how to do same but with my custom attributes?

I have one idea but I don't know how this one implement. So I know how to get current product id when you clicked on the color attribute[(through js code)](https://alanstorm.com/magento-2-extract-currently-selected-product-id/) 
then I  need  pass this id data to the controller via ajax. 
I need to know how exactly to do this, how to pass js data through ajax to controller and then call needed block on the category page every time when I click on the color attribute? ? 
When I will be know how to do that I get with this id data -  custom attribute values and call this template in the needed place.

So main question is: How to dynamically change custom attributes when click on the color attributes in the configurable product? 
And does it exist another way to achieve this ?
But if you have another solutions I ready to apply them.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Hi, it was few years ago, I guess I figured out how to do this , but I can't remember how.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, when choosing options, *images*, *price*, etc will change, but custom attributes.

In order to display the custom attribute of the selected product, you can create a [Plugin (Interceptor)](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html%5D) for `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable::getJsonConfig()` where you need to add missing custom attribute for each simple product.

Switching custom attribute when selecting an option can be implemented in `vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/base/web/js/swatch-renderer.js` and `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js` depending on the [type of attribute](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-create-configurable.html#product-variation-attribute-requirements).

---

I made free `VCT Product Info Switcher` module which update some attributes.